# haskell で codeeval の問題が解けない

Tags: haskell

CodeEvalのReverseWordsが解けません。
https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/8/

solve内でリストをreverseさせたいのですが、
リスト内の要素を文字列を反復してしまいます。

こういったとき、どういう風に考えれば解けますでしょうか？

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)

solve :: [String] -> [String]
solve ss = fmap reverse ss

main = do
    contents <- getContents
    mapM_ putStrLn $ solve $ lines contents
```

Answer (score 3):

この場合、まずwhitespaceで区切って`["Hello", "World"]`のようなリストを作ってから反転させる、と考えるべきです。

`words`で

```
> words "This is a pen"
> ["This", "is", "a", "pen"]
```

`unwords`で

```
> unwords ["pen","a","is","This"]
> "pen a is This"
```

のような変換ができます。

以下に正しい`solve`を掲載します。（マウスオーバーで表示します。）

> `solve :: [String] -> [String]`
>     `solve = fmap (unwords . reverse . words)`

Comment: `words`, `unwords` いずれも `Prelude` にもあると思いますが，ここで `Data.List.words` と書いておられるのに特別な意味はありますか？

Comment: @Yosh さん
すいません意味はないです。Preludeにあるの忘れてました。
回答を編集しました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: こちらこそありがとうございます！